# Widget's initialization works in an unexpected way

Tags: flutter

There is a simple statefull widget (screen)

```
class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  bool _isSwitched = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('init state');
    
    _getIsSwitched().then((value) { // gets it from preferences
      _isSwitched = value;
      print('_isSwitched was $_isSwitched');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
            children: [
              Switch(
                value: _isSwitched, // is not it should be updated here?
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isSwitched = value;
                    print(_isSwitched);
                    _setIsSwitched(_isSwitched); // sets it in preferences
                  });
                },
              ), ...
```

The problem is that the initialization works not as expected.
When the widget opened. I switched the switcher on and the value was saved in preferences. It's ok.

Then I go back to the previous page and open the widget (actualy a screen) again. It should be initialized then with the value from prefereses, yeah?

The init method prints the following

> init state
> _isSwitched was true

And it should be rendered as switchen on, but actualy it renders it as off.
Why the initialization not initialize the Switch widget when I open it the second time?

Comment: why aren't you calling `setState` inside `then` callback?

Comment: @pskink in the init method I have another one `then` which is also initialize in the same way another widget and it works without setState(). Then why the second `then` does not reqires setState() to work properly?

Comment: i cannot see your code so i cannot say, did `setState` work?

Comment: @pskink setState works. I had another widget which is below -  `slider`. and I had another variable `_sliderValue`. As you see in the post I have first `then` where I try to set `_isSwitched `. So in the same way I had another `then` below which is sets the `_sliderValue` if `_isSwitched == true` and acoording to this logic it should show or not to show the `Slider`. And actually it shows the `Slider` without any `setState` if the `Switch` was switched on. How doy you explain that? Why in the second case it doesn't requre the setStae method?

Comment: i cannot explain as i dont see your complete `initState` code

Comment: @pskink anyway I've got the idea of rebuilding a widget  when the value changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rebuild widget when the value changes so you should add **setState((){})**

For Example:

```
 _getIsSwitched().then((value) { // gets it from preferences
      setState(() {
        _isSwitched = value;
        print('_isSwitched was $_isSwitched');

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this!
>
> ```
> _getIsSwitched().then((value) { // gets it from preferences
>      setState(() {
>       _isSwitched = value;
>       print('_isSwitched was $_isSwitched');
>       });
>     });
> ```